# generate static unique number from a string in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a view to maintain a componentid and componentname.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vDimNIS]
AS
SELECT 
    IndicatorID as TINYINT
    IndicatorName as varchar(20)
FROM (
VALUES
(1,ant),
(2,bat),
(3,cat)
)AS Nis (IndicatorID , IndicatorName)
```

I would like to have an unique static IndicatorID for this table. What is the best to achieve this.

Comment: NEWID() will return a unique id every time

Comment: @adrianm that won't be static as it will create a unique value every time the view is called.

Comment: Yes,its dynamic. I want it something like based on the indicator-name string. Can we pass this string to generate a unique ID which is static ? do you a way to do the same

Comment: You can't create a unique int from a string. There are many more strings than ints so you will get collisions. Just store the data in table if you want the names to always have the same id.

Comment: So you suggest to give the Id's manually ?

Comment: Manual, identity column, NEWID(), sequence (SQL2012)

Comment: You can use ROW_NUMBER() function http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Answer (score 0):

i assume you would like this view to eventually point to a table, e.g. DimNis, where all your entries have an indicatorid. the easiest way i know to achieve this would be to use an identitiy. this way each time you insert a new indicatorname into your table, a new indicatorid will be issued:

```
create table DimNis
( indicatorid tinyint identity(1,1) not null
, indicatorname varchar(20));

insert into DimNis
( indicatorname )
values 
('ant');
insert into DimNis
( indicatorname )
values 
('bat');
insert into DimNis
( indicatorname )
values 
('cat');

select * from DimNis;
```

i hope this settles your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you add an identity column to your table (as suggested by Brett), the id will be autogenerated.
If you want to generate it on the fly, you can use ROW_NUMBER() that will give you a incremented number like identity, or you can use the hash function CHECKSUM that will compute an integer but may be with collisions.

The code with both Ids:

```
if object_id('vdimnis') is not null
    drop view vDimNis
    go
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vDimNIS]
AS
SELECT 
    row_number() over (order by IndicatorName) as IndicatorId,
    checksum(IndicatorName) as ChecksumId,
    cast( IndicatorName as varchar(20) ) as IndicatorName
FROM ( VALUES
        ('ant'),
        ('bat'),
        ('cat')
    ) AS Nis ( IndicatorName)
go
select * from vDimNis
```